# Javascript push Object to global array overwrites previous values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having this problem in Javascript: I want to get the longitude and latitude values from an array of Objects. This all works fine, but when I try to save it into a global array, it overwrites every previous value. The result is an array with 8 times the last pushed object.

Global array: `var _coordinates = [];`

```
function getCoordinates()
{
   mark = {};

   for(var key in _data)
   {
       if(_data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
           mark["lng"] = _data[key].long;
           mark["lat"] = _data[key].lat;
       }

       console.log(mark); // Returns different coordinates (yay)
       _coordinates.push(mark);

   }   

   console.log(_coordinates); // All coordinates are the same (meh)
}
```

This is my first time asking a question here. So if I forgot something, please say so.

Comment: What do you want the global and local variables to be, here? currently, `mark` is global, `_coordinates` is assumed + global, `_data` is assumed + global.

Comment: so problem is you are working on the same instance of `mark`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to declare and instantiate the `mark` object inside the `for` loop because right now you are modifying the same instance all the time:

```
function getCoordinates() {
    for(var key in _data) {
        var mark = {};
        if(_data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            mark["lng"] = _data[key].long;
            mark["lat"] = _data[key].lat;
        }
        _coordinates.push(mark);
    }   

    console.log(_coordinates);
}
```

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger, are you sure? Did you test it? Because this seems to work perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/bGGPX/ Why would this demo work if you were right?

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger The `var` declaration is indeed hoisted, but because `mark` is still being reassigned to a new object every loop, this still works.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. Been bitten to often by it, now I'm too paranoid ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are repeatedly modifying the same object. Your array ends up containing eight references to that one object.

To fix, move

```
mark = {};
```

into the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating the (global) variable `mark` in every loop. Do this instead

```
_coordinates.push({lng: _data[key].long, lat: data[key].lat});
```