# Array.push overriding the existing value instead of pushing new value

Tags: node.js, arrays

I am receiving data from the socket server and pushing it into an array. I am also checking if the data I received from the socket exists in an array, If it exists ignore it and if it doesn't push it into an existing array. For some reason though, the `socketarray.push` part seems to be overwriting previous data in the `socketarray` variable. No idea what am I doing wrong here

```
var socketarray = [];
socket.on('data', async data => {

    var server_data = data.toString();

    var parsed_result = m.parsingData(data.toString());

    if (parsed_result) {

        var car_id = parsed_result.car_id;

        var find_string = socketarray.findIndex(x => x.car_id == car_id);

        if (find_string === -1) {

            length = socketarray.push({ "car_id": car_id, });

        } else {

            console.log("already present");
            console.log(socketarray);

        }
    }
});
```

But there is also one weird thing which is happening. If I add this code

```
var length = socketarray.push({ "car_id": car_id,});
```

Before this line `var find_string = socketarray.findIndex(x => x.car_id == car_id);` which is basically putting a condition to make sure it doesn't save duplicate data. Then multiple data pushed successfully. But the only issue is the duplicity. So I have no idea why the code works before the conditional line and not after it.

Comment: So are you saying that `findIndex` returns -1 when it should in fact return something else? Btw, you should use === in the testing function.

Comment: @Christian It returns the right value. what I am saying is that my array simply doesn't store multiple values.

Comment: So the length of the array is always one?

Comment: @Christian yes True

Comment: Could it be that the array is re-initialized between invocations of the callback? Are you certain that the array isn't empty when entering the function?

Comment: @Christian Well the first time the `socketarray` would be empty and then I push the value in it. The value gets inserted, but the then the 2nd time it overrides the previous value

Comment: I have an issue Something like this But the solution doesn't work for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361699/javascript-push-object-to-global-array-overwrites-previous-values

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) If you didnt override `Array.protoype.push` its not possible that `.push` overrides your array/items.